# Why there is no canonical definition of javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, servlets

I've been doing this for some time, but now I've started to think.

HttpServletRequest is an interface defined in Java standard. Why do we always need a concrete, third-party definition of it, even for compilation, like following (using Apache):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Does this mean that writing purely standard, vendor-independent code which is using javax.servlet is not possible?

P.S. I know I can get Glassfish instead of Apache. But that would mean that I'll be using another concrete implementation rather that coding to a common interface.

P.P.S. Let me further clarify my question. HttpServletRequest interface (and I'm not talking about the implementation) is defined in both Apache and Glassfish libraries. One is licensed to Apache Software Foundation, another is copyrighted by Oracle. Is there such thing as canonical HttpServletRequest interface?

P.P.P.S. Looks like now I can further refine my question. If a standard defines an interface so tightly that there are no possible variations between multiple vendors - why don't make it a part of standard library? Why allowing multiple sources of truth?

Comment: Your dependency example has **nothing** to do with apache.

Comment: Define _Java standard_.

Comment: I suspect the confusion comes form the fact that the 3.0.1 jar (at least the one I was able to find) does contain an Apache implementation.  But if you look at, for example, the 3.0-alpha-1 jar, it is just the javax package (i.e. the standard API)

Answer (score 1):

> But that would mean that I'll be using another concrete implementation rather that coding to a common interface.

No, that's just completely not true.  When you add a dependency to `javax.servlet:servlet-api` you are specifying that you want to be coding to a common interface.  You will then also have to add a dependency to a specific implementation of that interface.

The point is that java out of the box could not possibly include all possible common interfaces for you to code against.  So, you have to acquire the interface you are interested in, and then you have to also acquire a specific implementation for it.

Comment: javax.servlet:servlet-api is common in the sense that it is commonly available, but not that it is canonical.

Comment: Well, yes.  I am not sure whether you are providing an objection or an observation by saying that.

Answer (score 0):

> javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest - is it part of Java EE?

Yes. `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` is an interface defined in Java EE specs. Read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html).

> Does this mean that writing purely standard, vendor-independent code
>   which is using javax.servlet is not possible?

You are writing vendor independent code when you use any class that implements this interface. That's the reason JEE includes it as an interface - a contract that **every** compliant servlet container (Tomcat or Glassfish or Weblogic) must obey. Imagine a non-compliant container provides a servlet api that doesn't obey the contract specified in JEE specs. In this case, you will actually have to write a **vendor-dependent** code to do things like retrieve parameters from request context or retrieve the session object tied to the request context.

However the fact that all the JEE compliant containers implement interfaces specified in JEE specs (e.g. `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpServletResponse`), you don't have to write any vendor specific code that would break if you switch between the containers.